# Inverse of the derivative for f(x) = f'(x)

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

I'm new so forgive my inexperience here.

The problem concerns the following:

$$ f: \Bbb R \to (0, \infty), f(x) = f'(x) $$

The first part of the problem involves showing f is increasing, this seemed simple since:

$$ f(x) > 0 => f'(x) > 0$$

Therefore $f$ is increasing.

The next part of the problem is what confuses me, I need to show that $(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{y} $ , that is to say the derivative of the inverse of $f$ is $1 \over y$

I can see how the problem makes sense, i.e. a function that satisfies $f(x) = f'(x)$ is $e^x $, the inverse of which is $\ln(x)$ and the derivative of that is $\frac{1}{x}$. However simply stating that $e^x$ is a function for$ f(x)$ doesn't seem like a worthwhile attempt at a solution as there isn't a unique solution for $f(x) = f'(x)$ .

Then I thought that$ f'(x) = f(x) $can be solved as a simple differential equation, but then that solution doesn't seem suitable for the course material (basic Analysis).

Is there any other solution to the second part of the problem I am overlooking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Derivative of the inverse function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_functions_and_differentiation).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Because $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$, for all $y$, we have

$$
f(f^{-1}(y)) = y
$$
and so, by the chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dy}f(f^{-1}(y)) = 1 \\
f'(f^{-1}(y)) \left(\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)\right) = 1
$$
and because $f' = f$,
$$
f(f^{-1}(y)) \left(\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)\right) = 1 \\
y \left(\frac{d}{dy}f^{-1}(y)\right) = 1 \\
$$

Comment: Very nice, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

that's a really nice problem, so I'm gonna post this solution anyway even though it doesn't follow the approach you proposed - simply consider $\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$ and calculate its derivative

Comment: Thanks for the input, the issue I'm having is if and how I justify just using $e^x$ without any obvious motivation behind it, is it just one of those things that you remember and quote?

Comment: well, after you've done some derivatives it's easy to note that $e^x$ satisfies this equation and once you have 'some' solution it's usually a good idea to play around with it to look for others. although I admit that in this particular case it's a thing I just remember cause the first time I've seen that I thought it was _really_ nice

Comment: Yeah, I recognised $e^x$ would work, I just wasn't sure whether I could just try something like that out of the blue with little justification.